# kerne panic on Mojave

Tags: macos, crash, macos-mojave

Summary:
We are facing kernel panic while copying some data to the allocated memory by kerne api vm_allocate();
Is there any alternate api/method for this problem. What is changed in 10.14?
Steps to Reproduce:

- We allocate kernel memory using following kernel API
  kern_return_t krt = kern_private.vm_allocate(map, &ptr, size, VM_FLAGS_ANYWHERE );
- Then we provide Read and Write permission to the allocated memory
  krt = mach_vm_protect(map, ptr, size, FALSE, VM_PROT_READ | VM_PROT_WRITE | VM_PROT_EXECUTE);
- Now when we try to copy some data to the allocated memory.
  ex memcpy(dest, data, size); where dest is  allocated memory location.
  }

Expected Results:
The data should copy to the allocated memory

Actual Results: 
OSX 10.14 is crashing.
For OSX < 10.14, the code was working fine.

Version/Build:
10.14 Beta (18A314h)

Comment: Public discussion of Apple's Developer Beta software is a breach of Apple's terms and conditions. Such questions should be posted to [Apple's forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/welcome), which has a specific section for Beta releases.